# How do I get the Theology tech?

Tags: kittens-game

In order to research Theology, it says I need 35 manuscripts, costing 51.98k furs, but I can only hunt for about 800 at a time and furs get used up over time so I can't stockpile them.  What can I do to get this research done?

Comment: The general rule for the game is, if you can't build it, build something else.  Eventually you will be able to build it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach is to simply *not* trying to stockpile furs.

Hunt, then turn the furs into parchment and wait for catpower to recover. Repeat until you have the required amount of parchment.

Comment: Meanwhile I put all my minerals into levelling up workshop, so that conversion of furs is most efficient.  My plan is to only convert to manuscripts when I have enough parchment, to get maximum benefit from the workshops.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to get a positive amount of furs is to build a tradepost. This will decrease the demand by 4%. This doesn't stack, but is 4% over the new number every time:

- level 1 tradepost: demand 100 - 4% = 96 demand
- level 2 tradepost: demand 96 - 4% = 92.16 demand

Add to this the option to send out hunters - more means faster hunting. You will eventually gather faster then you are consuming it.

If you want to gather even more furs and other luxurious items I suggest creating the mint building. In exchange for catpower and gold it will create furs and ivory.

Comment: Actually, Trade Posts do stack, but are subject to hyperbolic decrease once the total reduction exceeds 75% (which in practice you won't get before theology).

Comment: And Mints are less cost effective than hunting prior to the space age :-)

Comment: @meriton He was asking how he could achieve it, not if it was cost effective

Comment: There is no clear distinction between inefficient and useless in kittens game. When aiming for theology, people tend to have about 1200 max catpower. The benefit of mints are proportional to max catpower, and break even with hunting at about 12000. That is, in such an early stage of the game, hunting gives about 10 times more fur per catpower than mints, and does not use up precious gold :-)

Answer (score 1):

- You don't need to store all these furs at once. That is, you can accumulate catpower, then hunt and craft parchments immediately, so only leftover parchment gets consumed. However, luxuxy resource consumption increases happiness and kitten productivity, which may actually benefit you more than the fur consumed. As a rule of thumb, luxury consumption is worth it if you have bolas and bows (or paragon), in particular if happiness is below 100%.

  - if you choose to consume fur as luxury resource, you can reduce its consumption with trade posts.
- You can boost hunting returns with the appropriate workshop upgrades.
- You can boost the production of crafted resources (such as parchment and manuscripts) by building more workshops.
- You can increase catpower production by assigning more kittens as hunters.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the resources for an upgrade/building are indented like that it means you have to craft them into whatever is above them, so to get the manuscripts you need to craft parchment and to craft parchment you need furs etc.

It's also important to note that parchments are not a consumable rare resource like furs are, so by crafting your furs into parchment you are essentially "saving" them. Additionally, building trading posts will reduce how fast they're consumed. Mints (a building you unlock later) will produce furs for you as well. Having higher populations for higher cat power caps will also help you get furs faster.